# How can i get resources ( pictures ) from .dll file?

Tags: c#, .net

i put a .dll file in .net reflector 
then reflector shows a folder named 'Resources'.
I hope to reuse the pictures in that folder.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Reflection to do this.

Try the `GetManifestResourceStream` method of the Assembly class.  This should return a Stream object which can represent the embedded resource.

I think something like this should do the trick, but it is possible you should use another overload of GetManifestResourceStream:

```
Image.FromStream (theAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream ("resourcename");
```